# Finding Unghosted page using PowerShell Script in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer, powershell-script

I've a requirement to find out the unghosted page means page which are created using SharePoint designer using powershell script in SharePoint 2007. It should include the custom list forms as well.

Any help would be much appreciated.